# Wrong vertical space in theorem environment closed by an equation

Tags: spacing, equations, theorems

It happens that LaTeX, to fill a page vertically, adds extra spaces around equation environments (and other vertical spaces). Now suppose I have a theorem environment (using amsthm) which ends with an equation, like:

```
\begin{theorem}
  It holds
  \begin{equation}
    2+2=4
  \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Straightforward.
\end{proof}
```

and suppose that this piece of code rendered inside a page which is strechted vertically by LaTeX. Then LaTeX adds the extra vertical space only BEFORE the equation, and not after, and this looks ugly. Where is the problem?

EDIT: The problem appears only if I use a customized theorem style. So the question is: how should I use the command \newtheoremstyle so that the spacing is handled properly? For example

```
\newtheoremstyle{myplain} {2cm}% ⟨Space above⟩
{2cm}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
```

gives the problem above, while

```
\newtheoremstyle{myplain} {\topsep}% ⟨Space above⟩
{\topsep}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
```

does not.

EDIT2: A working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{myplain} {2cm}% ⟨Space above⟩
{2cm}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{myplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  It holds
  \begin{equation}
    2+2=4
  \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Straightforward.
\end{proof}

\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip

\begin{gather}
  2\\
  2\\
  2\\
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you mock up a little document that shows the situation?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Trying to do that, I found out that the problem appears only if I have a personal theorem style (defined through \newtheoremstyle). I edit the question.

Comment: Please expand your code snippet into a full working example, providing information on the document class you use as well as any theorem-related packages (e.g., `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, `thmtools`, etc.).

Comment: Isn't that just normal page stretch because of all those `\bigskip`s

Comment: @daleif I used the `\bigskip`'s just to produce a short working example. Notice that you don't see the space generated by the bigskips: this space is ignored by LaTeX since it is between two pages. The point is that the space over the equation is much bigger than the space under.

Answer (score 6):

That's some interesting behaviour you observed! You could regard this as kind of a bug in the LaTeX kernel. So what's happening here? There's some vertical space below the display (`\belowdisplayskip`) *and* after the theorem (the `\thm@postskip` of `2cm` that you specified). Now LaTeX is designed such that it doesn't add the *sum* but the *larger one* of those two vertical spaces (which is good).

The problem arises in how the larger of the spaces is chosen. This is done in LaTeX's `\@xaddvskip`, which only compares the "natural length" components of the spaces, but not the available stretch and shrink. In your case, `\belowdisplayskip` is `4.19998pt plus 4.19998pt` and `\thm@postskip` is `56.9055pt`. Usually the latter is larger, but you have a situation where the space is stretched about 128 times more than generally permitted (which is why you get an `Underfull \vbox` warning!). Therefore, `\belowdisplayskip` is actually the larger of the two spaces, but `\@xaddvskip` adds only the smaller `\thm@postskip` of `2cm` below the display.

In my opinion, a good solution is to work with the *maximum* of the two vertical spaces, in the following sense: use the maximum of the natural and stretch components, and the minimum of the shrink components. I've implemented an appropriate modification of `\@xaddvskip` in the code below. In the left you see the output of your code, in the right the output produced with the modified `\@xaddvskip`:

[image: original output]     
[image: improved output]

You can see that in the improved (right) version there's a bit more space below the equation than above. The reason is that above the equation `\abovedisplayskip` is used (`4.19998pt plus 4.19998pt`), and below the maximum of `\belowdisplayskip` and `\thm@postskip`, which amounts to `56.9055pt plus 4.19998pt`, so about `52.7pt` more than above. And that's good, since you wanted additional space below the theorem!

Note that the following code is just a proof of concept, it doesn't work as it should if infinite stretch or shrink components are involved.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@xaddvskip{%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb
    \edef\last@stretch{\the\gluestretch\lastskip}
    \edef\last@shrink{\the\glueshrink\lastskip}
    \edef\next@stretch{\the\gluestretch\@tempskipb}
    \edef\next@shrink{\the\glueshrink\@tempskipb}
    \vskip-\lastskip
    \dimen@=\@tempskipb
    \vskip\dimen@ plus
      \ifdim \last@stretch > \next@stretch
        \last@stretch
      \else
        \next@stretch
      \fi
    minus
      \ifdim \last@shrink < \next@shrink
        \last@shrink
      \else
        \next@shrink
      \fi
  \else
    \ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
      \else
        \advance\@tempskipb\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \vskip \@tempskipb
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{myplain} {2cm}% ⟨Space above⟩
{2cm}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{myplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  It holds
  \begin{equation}
    2+2=4
  \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Straightforward.
\end{proof}

\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip

\begin{gather}
  2\\
  2\\
  2\\
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Just for completeness, here's my original e-TeX-free implementation of `\getstretch` and `\getshrink`:

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`P=12
  \catcode`L=12
  \catcode`U=12
  \catcode`S=12
  \catcode`M=12
  \catcode`I=12
  \catcode`N=12
  \catcode`T=12
  \lowercase{
    \def\x{%
      \def\getstretch##1{\expandafter\get@stretch\the##1PLUS 0PT\endmarker}
      \def\get@stretch##1PLUS##2PT##3\endmarker{##2}
      \def\getshrink##1{\expandafter\get@shrink\the##1MINUS 0PT\endmarker}
      \def\get@shrink##1MINUS##2PT##3\endmarker{##2}
    }}
  \expandafter\endgroup\x
```

Comment: Interesting, that code might be useful for other projects.

Comment: @daleif: I had hoped so - thank you `:-)`

Comment: @daleif: With e-TeX it's a lot simpler ...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your "space above" and "space below" have no flexibility, while `\topsep` has. Add some flexibility:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{myplain}
  {2cm plus 1cm minus 0.5cm}% ⟨Space above⟩
  {2cm plus 1cm minus 0.5cm}% ⟨Space below⟩
  {\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
  {}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
  {\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
  {.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
  {.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
  {}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{myplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Some text above.

\begin{theorem}
  It holds
  \begin{equation}
    2+2=4
  \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Straightforward.
\end{proof}

some text for stretching
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives much more space _after_ the equation than before (due to the relatively large stretch of `1cm`). And varying the `1cm` gives sometimes more, sometimes less space after than before.